# Pivot table column grand total as percent of all grand totals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pivot table that shows A/R by the week it was calculated and the age of the claim.  The column labels are the Week label (Current, Week 2, Week 3) and then the age of the claim 0-30 Days, 31-60 Days, etc. The row label is the insurance company who is paying the claim.  I am doing grand totals on the columns, but I need to see the column grand total as a percent of the total grand total.  For example, I can see that my "Current" 0-30 grand total is $345 and my "Current" 31-60 grand total is $35.  But I need to know what % the 345 and 35 are of all of the "Current" grand totals.  I can see my "Week 2" 0-30 grand total is $1083, and the 31-60 grand total is $75, but I need to know what % the 1083 and 75 are of all of the "Week 2" column grand totals.  I know how to show an individual cell as a % of the row total, but can't seem to figure out how to do that for the grand totals row.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Stack! It's very difficult to understand from your input exact details, so for future questions try to provide workbook sample / screen or at list part of meaningful data typed here. However, the solution seems to be pretty simple (assuming I understood the input correctly): right click on the field you want to change, select `Value Field Settings...` and then select the option you need. For your needs I thing `% of total` is the choice:

[image: pivot field settings]

Hope that was helpful. In case you're happy with the solution - do not forget to tick the answer and therefore mark the thread solved. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Peter L.  Since I'm new I can't post an image, but here's a link to a screenshot that shows exactly what I'm trying to do.  I was sure I didn't explain it very well. http://content.screencast.com/users/brianburkett/folders/Jing/media/b1f3f35a-1806-49a2-b29d-354d108a3224/2013-01-28_0656.png

Comment: @BrianBurkett Thanks for the screen! So, try to apply my suggestions to the field(s) - for me it seems that it will do the job.

Comment: OK.  I applied your suggestion and ran into a couple of issues.  It does show the %, but converts the whole column to %.  That was fine because I could just add the same column to the pivot twice to show the value plus the %.  However, it calculates the % over the entire pivot, not the groupings separately.  So where I need it to just calculate over "Current" and "Week 2" separately.  Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianBurkett If you could share a sample file - that would be extremely helpful, since it's very difficult to produce exactly the same table that you have for tryouts.

Comment: OK.  I've posted a file with the pertinent columns intact.  http://www.webzax.com/test.xlsx  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The easiest solution so far - is to filter out **only one Week** using `Column labels` filter. In case you must have all the weeks at the same time - copy your pivot table several times and apply each required filter.